# How to retrieve variable in bamboo specs deploy file

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

I have the following deploy.yaml file

```
deployment:
  name: a deploy
  source-plan: dp

environments:
  - first.env

first.env:
  requirements:
    - name: excel_exec
  variables:
    - env_name: first.env
  tasks:
     - artifact-download:
         - destination: end1
           name: some.${env_name}.out
         - destination: end2
           name: another_end
```

the `${env_name}` is always empty though. What am I missing?